# Skip dates with no values in chart js

Tags: javascript, java, chart.js, momentjs

I would like to exclude the dates on the x-axis that has no values. Below is the image of my chart.

[What my chart currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGIzV.png)

Here is also my current code for the options in chart js

```
var options = {
                            responsive: true, 
                            maintainAspectRatio: false,
                            elements: {
                                line: {
                                    fill: false
                                }
                            },
                             style: {
                                  strokewidth: 10
                                },
                               
                             title: {
                                    display: true,  
                                    position: 'top',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    padding: 20
                                },
                            scales: { 
                                    xAxes:[{
                                        ticks: {
                                            z: 0,
                                            autoskip: false,
                                            callback: function(value, index, values){
                                                return new moment(value).format('L');
                                            }
                                        },
                                        type: 'time',
                                        time: {
                                            unit: 'week'                                    
                                        },
                                        scaleLabel: { display: true,
                                                      labelString: 'Date'}      
                                        }],
                                    yAxes: [{ 
                                        ticks: { beginAtZero:true ,
                                                 min: 0,
                                                 max: 5 } ,
                                scaleLabel: { display:     true,
                                              labelString: 'Skill Rating'}
                                        }] 
                            } 
                };
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your `series/data` to your chart, filter it

```js
let data = [...];
data = data.filter(v => v[0] && v[1]);
```